# How to diff javascript optimized by different optimizers

Tags: javascript, requirejs, google-closure-compiler, uglifyjs

I'm using the [RequireJS Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) on a project of mine and, by default, it uses UglifyJS. However, I was encountering an error (`'anim' is undefined`) when running on IE and Opera. Switching to the Closure Compiler with no other configuration change, just sticking to defaults, makes the problem go away.

How can I get an effective diff of the optimized output these two tools produce?

I don't mean to compare the capabilities of the two, either way is fine with me, but this may help point out a bug in one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to merge each minifier's output to single line in case it adds newlines to avoid some obscure old browser bugs (at least GCC does). Then you can use visual diff utility that highlight changes inside single line between two compared variants. At least `meld` and `winmerge` have this functionality. Most other should have it too.

Comment: Line wrapping in gcca is actually for proxy issues, not browsers

Answer (score 1):

Run both through closure compiler whitespace only mode with pretty printing enabled. This will make it easier to isolate the differences.